# Superqueens on a chessboard

Tags: puzzle

The superqueen is a chess piece that can move not only like a queen, but also like a knight. What is the maximal number of superqueens on an $8 \times 8$ chessboard such that no one can capture any other?

Additional information: Of course at most $8$, but it can be checked that every solution of the $8$-queens puzzle contains two queens that can capture each other by a knight move, so at most $7$. I can place $6$ of them. I am aware of the fact that on a $10 \times 10$ board, one can put $10$ of them.

Comment: If there is such an 7-queens solution, it can't be found by deleting one queen from a traditional 8-queen solution: all of the 12 fundamental solutions of the 8-queens puzzle ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eight_queens_puzzle#Solutions ) involve multiple independent pairs of queens a knight's move from each other.  This doesn't answer the question, of course, because there are 7-queen partial solutions of the traditional problem that can't be extended to an 8-queen solution.  It shouldn't take long to check all of them with a standard branch-and-bound search, though.

Comment: Have you tried computer search? Finding ordinary queen arrangements on an 8x8 board with no attack is an undergraduate coding exercise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice question.  If I programmed it right one cannot quite get 7.
There are dozens of ways to put 7 "superqueens" (a.k.a.
[Amazons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_(chess)))
on the board so that there's only one attacking pair, e.g.
a5,b3,d6,e7,f1,g4,h8 with one B-attack or
a2,c7,d4,e1,f8,g5,h3 with one N-attack.
I looked only for configurations with no R-attacks;
such a configuration can be represented
by a permutation of the numbers from 1 to 8 with one number missing.
None of the one-off configurations fits into a $7 \times 8$ board,
though it might be possible to do that with two "superqueens"
on the same rank or file and no other attacking pairs.

Here is the **gp** code.  "k" is the empty column,
which can be assumed to be 1, 2, 3, or 4 by symmetry.

```
Q(x1,y1,x2,y2) = ((x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 == 5) || (abs(x1-x2) == abs(y1-y2))
\\ true iff (x1,y1) is a N- or B-move from (x2,y2)

{
for(n=1,8!,
  a = numtoperm(8,n);
  for(k=1,4,
    s = sum(i=1,7,sum(j=i+1,8, (i!=k) && (j!=k) && Q(i,a[i],j,a[j])));
    if(s==0, print(k,a));
  )
)
}
```

The output is empty.  Changing "s==0" to "s==1" yields 172 solutions, including

```
2[5, 2, 3, 6, 7, 1, 4, 8]
2[2, 6, 7, 4, 1, 8, 5, 3]
```

which correspond to the B- and N-attack examples respectively.

P.S. Extending this calculation to a $9 \times 9$ board finds that
9 "superqueens" still cannot be accommodated, but there's
a unique permutation (up to the 8 board symmetries)
that fails at only one pair.  I do not exhibit this
configuration here because finding it might make for
a fun puzzle.  There's a number of nonattacking configurations
of 8 superqueens on this board; alas none has any symmetry, nor does any fit in an
$8 \times 9$ rectangle $-$ indeed only one (up to symmetry)
omits the second column.  I leave this last as a puzzle as well.

Answer (score 1):

See http://oeis.org/A133143 or my book http://problem64.beda.cz/silo/kotesovec_non_attacking_chess_pieces_2013_6ed.pdf, page 751-752.